# using time for a drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

[here's the page](http://valentin-degenne.com/demos/drop-down/index.html),

I'm trying to delay the drop-down menu so the user has few seconds to mousover it cause there's space between the element which triggers the menu and the menu itself.

```
$("#menu").hover(
    function(){ $("#dropdown").fadeIn(); },
    function(){ $("#dropdown").fadeOut(); }}
);
```

This works fine but when I mouseover the menu it wears off, my purpose is to make time for the user to put the cursor over it and that it remains present. well what's the best way to do that in jquery ?

Comment: You might want to consider supporting click as well. Finger driven devices seldom support the hover event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hoverIntent plugin helps with that: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: I'm not using a single element, but a <span> mouseover listener and a div that appears when the cursor is on this <span>. I messed a little with the title, my real purpose is to avoid the mouseout triggered function (the second callback in the hover) if the mouse hit the dropdown menu.

Comment: my bad, this is a great resource :) I finally get what I wanted ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is a way to delay the the `fadeOut`, then you can use the jQuery `delay` function:

`$("#dropdown").delay(1000).fadeOut();`

That will delay the fade by 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("#dropdown").delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
```

this will  pauses for 1000 milliseconds before fading in for 1000 milliseconds